# How can I make videos like Minute physics

Tags: video, software-recommendation

I understood the fairly simple process behind the older Minute physics videos.

But I would like to know what kind of software/workflow is used for these new videos. What can I learn to make these kind of videos?

I am primarily a programmer, attempting to change to making educational videos.

Answer (score 2):

He used this:

[image: a drawing tablet]
<sub>(source: [monoprice.com](http://images2.monoprice.com/productlargeimages/105941.jpg))</sub>

He probably captured all of that with a plugin for After Effects and just added images and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

It is same approaches, as before: he captured video as he drawing... Then added pictures and effects.

For more complex effects you need After Effects, but for more simple video, as just captured drawing process and images — you can use almost any video-editing software with timeline.

Comment: The figures don't look hand-drawn to me. They are too polished. But using some kind of handdrawn kinda font....or a graphics package.

Comment: He just know, how to draw... Or, please provide a timecode, where you think is not drawn object and not photo too.

Comment: The earlier videos were made manually on white paper. These are colored and uses design software tools. Something like sketchbook maybe? Any idea what software he could have used to handdraw on it using a graphic tablet?

Comment: You could use Animate (aka Flash) to do that, or draw the strokes in Illustrator and animate in After Effects. One thing you will need is a pressure-sensitive graphics tablet, like a Wacom.

Answer (score 1):

The style You mentioned is called "Explainer Videos". There is plenty techniques that might be used to make such videos.

One would be that You record Your own voice first and then You try to make the drawings / illustrations match what You were just saying.

The other way is to have drawings ready and try to commentate over them.

Where it comes to software itself try exploring multiple options.

- Adobe Illustrator
- Adobe After Effects
- Adobe Premiere Pro
- Adobe Audition

The list mentioned above would be my choice If I would start trying to get into such things.

The direct answer to the question "What can I learn to make this kind of videos?" would be:

- Drawing and or illustrating
- Animation
- Basic audio manipulation
- Composition in film

Or just try writing "How to make explainer videos" in any search engine for lots of material.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this must have been created on a tablet with a software called [Explain Everything](https://explaineverything.com/).
It is a great tool that allows you to record your own animations.

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop also has the ability to capture brush strokes and play them back. Similar to this:

But my guess is, most likely, After Effects. The drawn elements can be easily positioned,revealed and animated.

Answer (score 0):

he must have drawn it first. Then on After Effects, he inverted the colours and added some pictures and graphic texts. or used the photoshop action record feature and added images on after effects. don't know maybe wrong.